# How to compute utilization with python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
In [42]: df[['timestamp', 'elapsed']].head()
Out[42]:
                   timestamp  elapsed
0 2014-11-26 00:00:01.830556       13
1 2014-11-26 00:00:01.830706       14
2 2014-11-26 00:00:01.830158       18
3 2014-11-26 00:00:01.830355       19
4 2014-11-26 00:00:01.830512       24
```

The timestamp is the moment when the system received the query and the elapsed time is how many microseconds it took to process the query.

As there are multiple processes, queries are processed in parallel, but what I would like to know is how many queries do we process at the same time at most (and ideally, see display a graph of the usage, but that's not really my problem here). The granularity here is the second.

The problem is that it can happen (fairly regularly) that a query takes more than 1s to execute, or that we start processing a query at 00:00:01.99 and finish within the next second, so I can't just count the number of rows within a second.

What I would need would be to sum all the elapsed time within a specific second:
- if we start and finish within the same second, then add the whole elapsed time
- if we start before and end after the current second, then add 1s of processing time
- if we start in the current second, but end after, then add the time until the end of the second
- same if we started before the current second and end within it.

So far I just created a dataframe with all the seconds in a day, and iterate of my query dataframe, but this doesn't feel very efficient, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to go about solving this kind of problem.

Comment: Your questions seems contradictory to me: First you say, that the `granularity is the second`, but in the forth paragraph you go back to the exact elapsed time based on the timestamp?

Comment: I meant that the granularity of the aggregation is the second:

* second starting at 00:00:00: 1320ms elapsed
* second starting at 00:00:01: 900ms elapsed
* etc.

Comment: I think the clean way to do this is to implement the algorithm yourself. You basically have time intervals `(start, end)`. You can then e.g. build two interval priority queues: the `start_queue` sorted by the `start` and the `end_queue` sorted by the ends. You initialize by putting all intervals in the start queue and setting current to 0. For each step you pick the minimum from these both queues, if it is start, you put the interval into the `end_queue`, increment `current` and write down `(start, current)` else decrement `current` and write down `(end, current)`

Comment: I have over 20M rows, so ideally I'd be looking for a solution that doesn't require duplicating all the data. I know I can do it in chunks, but then I need to deal with the edges of the chunks specifically, so wondering if there's a cleaner way.